# Share OpenGL Context between Unity3d & Cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, unity-game-engine

We have project which includes cocos2d 2.0 + Native + Unity 3d.
 Unity3d & Cocos2d both uses glview, as there can be only one OpenGL context at a time we want 
 to  create common GLContext whose reference can be used by Cocos2d & unity3d.

We are not sure whether it is possible, If possible your suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can share an openGL context using EAGL Sharegroups.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts.html

I've never done that with unity though, but a quick googling showed this up which at a quick glance seems to do what you need.

https://github.com/bzgeb/pd-for-unity/blob/master/iOS/Classes/Unity/EAGLContextHelper.mm

hope this helps!